# Bootstrap Carousel Wont Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Everything works fine except.
Image wont slide from one to the next.
Could it be perhaps the images are to big.
I tried making them smaller with the width="" height="".
It only makes my images disappear. 
The preview and next are far from the images.
Can somebody help me figure out why.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <html>

    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/home/owner/Documents/Practice/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/home/owner/Documents/Practice/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/home/owner/Documents/Practice/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/home/owner/Documents/Practice/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>



    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <ol class = "carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
    <li data-target = "#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
    </ol>


    <div class ="carousel-inner">

    <div class = "item active">
    <img src = "/home/owner/Documents/Practice/images/Durban.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class = "item">
    <img src = "/home/owner/Documents/Practice/images/Johannesburg.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class = "item">
    <img src = "/home/owner/Documents/Practice/images/Lighthouse.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>


    </div>

    <a class= "carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide ="prev">
    <span class= "icon-prev"></span>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide ="next">
    <span class = "icon-next"></span>

    </div>




    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: are the images showing? at all

Comment: Check your [console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers), any errors?

Comment: Please post your css too here.

Comment: Jquery must be included **before** bootstrap.js. Plus you are loading both the minified and non-minified versions.

Comment: ...and load your javascript at the end of the document damn it!

Comment: Wow it so simple, plug ins.